# Missing an assembly reference? (The type or namespace name `RouteMe' could not be found.)

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm interested in easily adding a MapBox to my iOS app that is being constructed with Xamarin. I haven't found much online on specifically Mapbox / C# implementation, however I did find this below:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Route-Me

which is an incomplete binding of Route Me (Mapbox alternative). I've cloned the files and opened in Xamarin, however I'm getting an error. Here is an image of what happens:

http://s48.photobucket.com/user/marcanthonysabin/media/ScreenShot2014-12-02at114526AM_zpsd014a3d4.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this issue and use the Route Me bindings, or perhaps any alternative paths I can take besides this one?? Any information at all is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: do you have the actual .Dll ? if so then add a reference to it from within your solution.. do you know how to add external references via VS

Comment: No... I guess I'm pretty new and unsure if I have a .Dll, nor do I know how to add external references. Do you happen to have any links you can share on this, or perhaps a walkthrough on getting Route Me working? Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) please show more effort than just stating `I don't know how..this is what google is used for here is a link to start off with

Comment: Yeah, I did use google, and really did look all over. I haven't used Xamarin much at all so I was hoping for a more thorough explanation of this sort of thing. I'm going to try out the link you sent, and I do appreciate you sending it. But if you didn't send that link, that would definitely be one I would skip over, as it says Visual Studio, and also "5 out of 21 rated this helpful". Thanks

Comment: are you using Visual Studio to code this..? if not here is a link of the [Introduction to Xamarin Studio](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introducing_xamarin_studio/)

Comment: Yeah i'm using Xamarin, and yeah i've been through the introduction already. I'm really eager to know how to reference the .dll from within my solution, and I guess a thorough explanation of the process.